# Adding large file manually inside the project in android studio

Tags: android

My project is all about media player. I want to store manually hundreds of mp3 files in my project but the problem is I don't know where I can put the large file which is the file size is 300MB into my project. I already search many times on google but the answer is always putting the file into ExternalDirectory by using this code.

```
File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null)+"/");
```

The problem of this code is you can only store a file to this directory once you downloaded the file. Since my project is an offline app, I don't need an internet connection to it

Here is my first attempt.
I put my one mp3 file to asset folder which is the size is 5mb and make a copy to another directory 
`File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null)+"/newFile.mp3");` please take a look below.

```
private void copyFile() {
            InputStream inputStream;
            try {
                inputStream = getAssets().open("raw/original.mp3");
                File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null)+"/newFile.mp3");

                OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int length;
                while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer,0,length);
                }
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
                inputStream.close();
                Log.d(TAG, "copyFile: copied ");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

the code above works fine. I can see that the file was successfully copied but the problem is during my research they said that asset folder or res/raw folder has a storage limit it means that I can only store a file in asset folder with a file size less than 5MB (I am not sure).

My question is what is the best way to manually store mp3 files (300MB) to my project(without downloading the files)?

Thanks and advance.

Comment: Well didnt you try to put all files in assets as test? Then you are the one to tell us if even the largest file came through ok. How big was the .apk then?

Comment: `but the answer is always putting the file into ExternalDirectory by using this code.` That is nonsense as you are asking how to ship your apk file with the mp3 files.

Comment: I didn't try it though. I doubt to store the files to the asset folders because when I do that the size requirements to install the app will be doubled because the asset folder is read-only. I can't delete the file inside the asset folder after the files copied so instead of 300MB install requirements it will be doubled to 600MB.  If there is no alternative way to my problem so maybe I will stick to the assets folder. Thank you @blackapps